# regex to split text after newlines

Tags: php, regex, split

I have a text that is "split" by 2 newlines. I now need an array containing all those texts in one array key.

Imagine the following text

```
Lorem ipsum###Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et

Lorem ipsum###Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et

Lorem ipsum###Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et

Lorem ipsum

Lorem ipsum

Lorem ipsum
```

Every textblock should be an own array element, meaning, I would need to have 6 at the end.

I tried it like this

```
$bulletList = preg_split('/[\s\n]{2,}/', $text);
```

and like this

```
$bulletList = preg_split('/[\n]/', text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

but every time, I have an array index with the correct text, and then an index with the following content.

`[1]=> string(6) "
"`

As you can see, the newlines are getting into a new text. How would I have only the values in one array?

I mean, I could simply use `continue` in the foreach loop if it's an empty string or by using `modulo`, however, there must be a way to have this correct when getting the data, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split` as:

```
print_r ( preg_split('/\R{2,}/', $data) );
```

`\R` matches any newline in PCRE.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem ipsum###Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
    [1] => Lorem ipsum###Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
    [2] => Lorem ipsum###Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et
    [3] => Lorem ipsum
    [4] => Lorem ipsum
    [5] => Lorem ipsum

)
```

**Edit:** For lines delimited by `<br />` use this:

```
print_r ( preg_split('/(?:\R|<br[^>]*>){2,}/', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) );
```

Comment: Hey, 

thanks for the output, however this doesn't work for me. Is it different with PCRE and PHP? I'm getting just the whole string as one

Comment: @Tushar I just tested it. However the problem that there are array indexes with whitespaces still persists

Comment: you might consider adding the limit param and PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY flag, ex. `print_r ( preg_split('/\R{2,}/', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) );`

Comment: This is weird, when I'm writing the string directly, the script of @anubhava works without problems. But when I'm getting the value from the database it doesn't work. What could that be?

Comment: I found, that the text from the database splits the texts not with `\n` or something like that, but instead with `<br />
`

Comment: Ah ok so try this one: `print_r ( preg_split('/(?:\R|<br[^>]*>){2,}/', $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) );`